# how to change hintText color in textField Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

this is my code,and I want to change the hintText Color, how to do?

```
    "#email":{
    width: '70%',
    left:'13%',
    font:{
        fontSize:'20sp'
    },
    color: '#fff',
    hintText:'请输入手机号',
    borderColor:'transparent',
    bottom:'2%',
    //backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer is horrendous, please do not use that method. See answer provided by @gjerlow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37226098/971557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can't i tried before
here what i did to change the hint color and font
you need to create a `view`, `textfeild` and `label` with adding change listener on `textfeild` to show or hide the hint

```
 var mh_view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : "white",
    height : "40dp",
    top : "224dp",
    left : "10dp",
    right : "10dp",
    width : Ti.UI.FILL
});
var mail_hint = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color : "#88817F",
    font : {
        fontFamily : customfont2,
        fontSize : "15dp"
    },
    left : "47dp",
    //top:"14dp",
    text : "E-mail"
});
mh_view.add(mail_hint);
var mail = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    backgroundImage : "/images/trans.png",
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : "40dp",
    top : "224dp",
    left : "10dp",
    right : "10dp",
    bubbleParent:false,
    paddingLeft : "47dp"
    // hintText:"E-mail"
});

var visible = true;
mail.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (visible) {
        mail_hint.hide();
    } else {
        if ((mail.value).length == 0)
            mail_hint.show();
    }
    visible = !visible;

});
```

hope it help :)

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using AttributedString and AttributedHintText, which supports both Android and iOS.

```js
var emailHintText = "Your email";

var attributedEmailHintText = Titanium.UI.createAttributedString({
  text : emailHintText,
  attributes : [{
   type : Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
   range : [0, emailHintText.length],
   value : '#88817F',
  }]
 });

$.email.setAttributedHintText(attributedEmailHintText);
```

AttributedString will also allow you to add more attributes to your string/hintText in addition to color. Read about it in Appcelerators Documentation:

[AttributedString Foreground Color](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Attributed_Strings-section-37538231_AttributedStrings-ForegroundColor)

[Ti.UI.AttributedString](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AttributedString)

**UPDATE 15.08.16**

After the Titanium SDK 5.4.0.GA release, iOS now support the property `hintTextColor` and the method `setHintTextColor` for TextFields. Read more in the [Titanium SDK Release Notes for iOS](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_Release_Notes-section-43316487_TitaniumSDKReleaseNotes-iOSPlatform)

Comment: +1 This is the best answer, and the only one that is cross-platform-correct. Forget all that hogwash with hiding and showing elements.  OP, please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, @NoelBaron. It is also easy to make a function of it to prevent duplicate code when multiple TextFields are used or a TextField needs different hintTexts.

Answer (score 2):

Just add hintTextColor property.

```
"#email":{
    width: '70%',
    left:'13%',
    font:{
        fontSize:'20sp'
    },
    color: '#fff',
    hintText:'Hint Text',
    hintTextColor : "#787878",
    borderColor:'transparent',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: This works as expected in latest SDKs.. This should now be the answer IMHO

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a theme for android with such properties.
you can find how to do that http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes

they have a good doccument for it

Answer (score 0):

For those that were searching around, you can do this using "hintTextColor", you can use it for a textfield, but I used it for a search bar, see example below:

```
var searchInputBox = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
   backgroundColor:'#fff',
   hintTextColor:'#777',
   backgroundFocusedColor: "red",
   color: "#000",
   showCancel:true,
   height: 60,
   width: "94%",
   top: 100,
   left: "3%",
   hintText: "E.g. Bananas...",
   font: { color: "#fff"},
});
```

I found this mentioned here in a post: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18433

Answer (score -1):

I think,
Just put color:'red'
it will show your text as well as hint text in red color

Comment: no !  it's always gray whatever the font color is .